# TX RX text via gnuradio using hack rf

Tags: demodulation, gnuradio, software-defined-radio, gmsk

I have a problem here - either I'm stupid or my hack rf is broken
I am trying to send text via 2 hackrf [like in this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kplMaL7e2l4&ab_channel=NH)using GMSK
The simulation returns the text is correct, but when I run the rf hack it returns garbage to me, what could be the problem?

```
TX RX
```

[image]

```
Simulation
```

[image]

```
I get it
```

[image]

```
the text I am sending
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mitigate duplicating efforts, I [talked about this with Nortan on the GNU Radio Chat](https://matrix.to/#/!PiiKkGTcBDLmPnxhoT:gnuradio.org/$j1FZVNnS-yxFElDa5XSYFNpyhi5SwJQUz1ICab3p21A?via=gnuradio.org&via=libera.chat&via=matrix.org) in the meantime; reproducing the exchange here:

> cutting things short there: that video uses GNU Radio3.7, and especially very very broken blocks that we removed because we didn't figure out how to fix them. So, instead of random videos on youtube I'd recommend https://tutorials.gnuradio.org, there's a packet-based digital communications tutorial!
>
> what you're missing in your flow graph is framing; your receiver simply can't know what the first symbol of a byte is.

So, the problem here is that receiver can't know what is noise and what the starting symbol of the first byte of a transmission.